# Boot failed - Initramfs dropped shell with NVMe disks not present

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I recently changed laptop and upgraded my M2 SATA having Ubuntu into a M2 NVMe via `dd`. Firstly I booted into livecd (ubuntu 22), made a chroot environment, cleared all the `linux-image-*` and `linux-headers-*` packages and reinstalled `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`, install a 5.4 version of the kernel on Ubuntu 20. I then proceeded to rebuild Grub and Initramfs.

While booting, the system hangs and finally drops an initramfs' busybox shell, to which I can notice my `/dev/nvme*` disks don't appear, while my plugged in LiveCD appears as `/dev/sda`.

The content of `/proc/modules` return that `nvme`, `nvme_core`, and `vmd` modules are loaded in, with VMD being enabled in the BIOS.

To note the `/dev/nvme*` volumes are available when I do a from-scratch installation from livecd. Help would be appreciated on this matter.

Comment: I have been able to successfully boot after installing Ubuntu 22, and hijacking the /boot partition to point to my Ubuntu 20 (the system is a bit unstable though).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. It turned out that a NVME boot required one of the modules from the linux-modules-extra-* package. So I had to do a boot from
Ubuntu-Live-Image, open a shell, and do about this:

```
sudo -i

mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /proc /sys /run
do
    mount -o bind $i /mnt/$i
done

chroot /mnt /bin/bash

dpkg -l | grep linux-image   # Find your kernel package, e.g. linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic

apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic  # Install what is missing

exit  # chroot

for i in /mnt/dev /mnt/proc /mnt&sys /mnt/run /mnt/boot/efi /mnt
do
    umount $i
done
```

Please note that details like version number or device names may have to be adapted to your case. If you are uncertain you may use the following command to get a better idea about your device names or map the UUID you may have seen
in the boot error message:

```
lsblk -f
```

Comment: Hmm I think you've missed the part that you chroot into `/mnt` before dpkg and apt-get and exit the chroot after them?

Comment: Your are right - just scrap the bits & pierces from the memory and forgot that part.